# Pytorch get "RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered"

Tags: pytorch

Snippet from my code :

```
max = torch.tensor([3])
if USE_CUDA: max = max.cuda()
max_embedding = self.max_embedding(max) # dim of max_embedding: 1*5

item_dict = {}
for item in item_list:
    item = torch.tensor(item)
    if USE_CUDA: item = item.cuda()
    item_embedding = self.item_embedding(item) # dim of item_embedding: 1*20

embedded = torch.cat((max_embedding, item_embedding), 1)
```

But I get error of "RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered".
The output by adding `CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1`:

```
/pytorch/aten/src/THC/THCTensorIndex.cu:308: void indexSelectSmallIndex(TensorInfo<T, IndexType>, TensorInfo<long, IndexType>, int, int, IndexType, long) [with T = float, IndexType = unsigned int, DstDim =2, SrcDim = 2, IdxDim = -2: block: [0,0,0], thread: [0,0,0] Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.
/pytorch/aten/src/THC/THCTensorIndex.cu:308: void indexSelectSmallIndex(TensorInfo<T, IndexType>, TensorInfo<long, IndexType>, int, int, IndexType, long) [with T = float, IndexType = unsigned int, DstDim =2, SrcDim = 2, IdxDim = -2: block: [0,0,0], thread: [1,0,0] Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.
/pytorch/aten/src/THC/THCTensorIndex.cu:308: void indexSelectSmallIndex(TensorInfo<T, IndexType>, TensorInfo<long, IndexType>, int, int, IndexType, long) [with T = float, IndexType = unsigned int, DstDim =2, SrcDim = 2, IdxDim = -2: block: [0,0,0], thread: [2,0,0] Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.
/pytorch/aten/src/THC/THCTensorIndex.cu:308: void indexSelectSmallIndex(TensorInfo<T, IndexType>, TensorInfo<long, IndexType>, int, int, IndexType, long) [with T = float, IndexType = unsigned int, DstDim =2, SrcDim = 2, IdxDim = -2: block: [0,0,0], thread: [3,0,0] Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.
/pytorch/aten/src/THC/THCTensorIndex.cu:308: void indexSelectSmallIndex(TensorInfo<T, IndexType>, TensorInfo<long, IndexType>, int, int, IndexType, long) [with T = float, IndexType = unsigned int, DstDim =2, SrcDim = 2, IdxDim = -2: block: [0,0,0], thread: [4,0,0] Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mytest.py", line 33, in <module>
     if USE_CUDA: item = item.cuda()
RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Check [this link](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/1204). This guy had the same issue because some of his labels had negative values.

Comment: What is your GPU and what is the result of `torch.version.cuda`?

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical case of index-out-of-bounds error manifested itself in the context of embeddings. Check this [link](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/solved-assertion-srcindex-srcselectdimsize-failed-on-gpu-for-torch-cat/1804) for solution to a similar problem.